# How many cities can you have at the same time in Civilization 6?

Tags: civilization-6

How many cities can you have at the same time in Civilization 6?

It's out of curiosity, but I think its important knows how many cities you can have in order to do more in a single turn.

Comment: I don't think there is a limit. I remember in an older version once you reached the end of the city names, it would start repeating the names but placed the word "new" in front of it. (Such as New Washington D.C.).

Comment: What happens if you exhaust it multiple times? Do you eventually get "New New New New York"?

Comment: @Ethan That would require you to put down at least 121 cities and not renaming them. each city needs roughly 30 hexes, so that's 3630 hexes. Assuming your map generates 40% land, 10% mountains and 50% water, that means you need a map of roughly 9000 hexes, which is slightly smaller than the Huge size. Assuming you settle a city every 2 turns from the start, you got just enough time in a regular 250 turn match to build 121 cities.

Comment: you can build, allow capture and raze cities continuously

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no upper limit on the number of cities you can have in Civ VI. However, your Amenities gained from Luxury Resources can only give a bonus to four cities (six for Aztecs), so every city created beyond the fourth will reduce the Amenities available in each city. Since Amenities impact how productive your cities are you'll want to avoid expanding too fast if the Amenities in your cities are already fairly low.

Other than concerns about Amenities though there really isn't much of a negative to founding more cities, and you'll usually get some benefit from every city you create.